# Getting two values for a colums which is not PK

Tags: oracle

I have a table with 4 columns

```
id,C_number,C_reopen,c_closed
```

Where `id` is the pk.
I want to pull rows which has two different values for `c_closed` for the same `c_number`. Not `c_number` is not pk hence can have duplicate values.

```
create table claim 
( 
      id not null number(10),
      c_number string(50), 
      c_reopen date,
      c_closed(date)
);
```

Sample data:

```
insert into claim(111 , 'c101', '10/1/12015','15/1/2015');
insert into claim(112, 'c102','10/2/2015','15/2/2015');
insert into claim(113,'c101','18/1/2015','28/1/2015');
```

So, here for the same `c_number`-`c101`, I have two closed one is `15/1/2015` and the other `28/1/2015`. I want a query to retrieve `c_cumber` which have more than one value for close.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT c_number 
FROM CLAIM 
GROUP BY c_number 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c_closed) > 1;
```

As we have to retrieve the **c_number** where the rows have more than one unique **c_closed** value for every **c_number** , we have to do the following things: 
 1. Group the rows by **c_number** , so we will get rows for every unique **c_number**. 
 2. Within every group (each unique value of **c_number** causes a new group, 10 unique **c_number** = 10 groups) use ***HAVING CLAUSE*** to filter out groups where each unique **c_number** has only one unique **c_closed** value.

To count only distinct **c_closed** values you have to use **DISTINCT**. 
**HAVING CLAUSE** it is like **WHERE CLAUSE** but it is used after aggregation when all rows with the same values of chosen columns collapse into one row.